# VPN Setup: Smoothwall + Cradlepoint MBR1000 + Windows 7 + FileMaker Server

Tags: windows-7, router, vpn, firewall, filemaker

I am trying to set up a VPN on my company's network so that my boss can work on FileMaker from home. We use FileMaker Server 11 Advanced to host our FileMaker application; I'd open port 5003 and DynDNS the IP and just log in that way, but I feel that it's far too insecure for what we need. (We know of some local competing businesses that use the same software that we do, and it would be awful if one of them got access to our company's files.) So, I'm trying to set up a VPN.

My boss's laptop is running Windows 7 Enterprise, so I assumed that it would be easiest to VPN him in to another computer on our network running Windows 7. (Our network is a hodge-podge of all sorts of machines - some running 7, some running XP, a dedicated firewall running Smoothwall, at least one that's running SME Server 7.4, a Mac Mini with Leopard Server, and a backup server running Ubuntu 10.10. It's exciting, to say the least.)

Our internet connection is routed first through Smoothwall, then into a Cradlepoint MBR1000 router with access point, then into a 16-port switch and to the rest of the computers. I enabled VPN through Smoothwall's web interface, and I forwarded port 1723 to the Windows 7 computer's local IP in Cradlepoint's settings (under Advanced - Gaming, because that's apparently where I needed to forward the port).

After all that, I got on to the 7 box that I planned to VPN into and set it up as a VPN server. (It was standard procedure and I don't think that there was much room for error there, so I'll not go into details.)

When I got on a different network ("different" as in "drove to my boss's house to test it") and tried to connect, I got the dreaded Error 800. The username and password authenticate fine, but I can't seem to initiate the rest of the connection.

There is a pretty significant lack of information on the internet regarding VPNing with Windows 7, so not only am I hoping to get help, but I'm also hoping that this article could be good community wiki material.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I forwarded the Windows 7 computer at work's external IP to a DynDNS domain, and I've been trying to connect through that. (I have the same setup in place to rsync some files over ssh to a remote server, so I am fairly certain that works.)

Answer (score 1):

So since you mentioned having a Windows 2003 server, I would suggest setting up RRAS on that and mixing it into the DynDNS mix as the target host. See where that leads you for now.

Should be fairly easy to VPN from Win7 to WinServer2k3

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help in chat... I'll try this and get back with you.